# Converting a HTML page to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jspdf

I want to convert a HTML page like the given one having a form in it to PDF using jsPDF, but the table isn't getting printed with all of the columns in it. So I am thinking to print it on a landscape page but I am confused with the size measurements. Can anyone help me to get it done correctly?
And this is how it gets printed:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script>
(function () {  
  var  
  form = $('.form'),  
      cache_width = form.width(),  
      a4 = [595.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height  
      
  $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {  
    $('body').scrollTop(0);  
    createPDF();  
  });  
  //create pdf  
  function createPDF() {  
    getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {  
      var  
      img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),  
          doc = new jsPDF({ 
            unit: 'px',  
            format: 'a4'
          });  
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);  
      doc.save('suman-html-to-pdf.pdf');  
      form.width(cache_width);  
    });  
  }  
  
  // create canvas object  
  function getCanvas() {  
    form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');  
    return html2canvas(form, {  
      imageTimeout: 2000,  
      removeContainer: true  
    });  
  }  
}());  
</script>

<script>  
  /* 
     * jQuery helper plugin for examples and tests 
     */  
(function ($) {  
  $.fn.html2canvas = function (options) {  
    var date = new Date(),  
        $message = null,  
        timeoutTimer = false,  
        timer = date.getTime();  
    html2canvas.logging = options && options.logging;  
    html2canvas.Preload(this[0], $.extend({  
      complete: function (images) {  
        var queue = html2canvas.Parse(this[0], images, options),  
            $canvas = $(html2canvas.Renderer(queue, options)),  
            finishTime = new Date();  
            
        $canvas.css({ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }).appendTo(document.body);  
        $canvas.siblings().toggle();  
        
        $(window).click(function () {  
          if (!$canvas.is(':visible')) {  
            $canvas.toggle().siblings().toggle();  
            throwMessage("Canvas Render visible");  
          } else {  
            $canvas.siblings().toggle();  
            $canvas.toggle();  
            throwMessage("Canvas Render hidden");  
          }  
        });  
        throwMessage('Screenshot created in ' + ((finishTime.getTime() - timer) / 1000) + " seconds<br />", 4000);  
      }  
    }, options));  
    
    function throwMessage(msg, duration) {  
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);  
      timeoutTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {  
        $message.fadeOut(function () {  
          $message.remove();  
        });  
      }, duration || 2000);  
      if ($message)  
        $message.remove();  
      $message = $('<div ></div>').html(msg).css({  
        margin: 0,  
        padding: 10,  
        background: "#000",  
        opacity: 0.7,  
        position: "fixed",  
        top: 10,  
        right: 5,  
        fontFamily: 'Tahoma',  
        color: '#fff',  
        fontSize: 12,  
        borderRadius: 12,  
        width: 'auto',  
        height: 'auto',  
        textAlign: 'center',  
        textDecoration: 'none'  
      }).hide().fadeIn().appendTo('body');  
    }  
  };  
})(jQuery);  
</script>
```